# Maven Profiles error with -Dcucumber.options with multiple tags

Tags: maven, cucumber, pom.xml, serenity-bdd

The following code below is throwing a cannot resolve symbol when trying to create a profile in my pom. I can run this with no issues with one tag, but multiple cannot resolve the issue. I tried --tags @value, @value and --tags @value --tags @value, but they still give the same error.

Can someone help with this error? I am getting cannot resolve symbol 'firstTag'

```
    <profile>
        <id>Test</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/**/Runner.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <argLine>
                            -Dcucumber.options="--tags @firstTag, @secondTag"
                        </argLine>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"-Dcucumber.options=--tags '@firstTag and @secondTag'"
```